# Array within Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

**CODE :**

```
<body>
    <div class="con">
        <button class="tabs"> HTM </button>
        <button class="tabs"> JS </button>
        <button class="tabs"> CSS </button>
    </div>
    <div class="data"> </div>
    <script>
        var bu = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
        var contents=["HTML", "js" , "css"];
        for(var i=0; i<bu.length; i++){ 
            alert(contents[i]);
            bu[i].onclick=function(){
                alert(contents[i]);
                document.getElementsByClassName("data").innerHTML = content[i]; 
                }
        }
    </script>
<body>
```

In the above program, the alert function next to for statement executed properly. But, it doesn't work within "function". What I
think is, the statement within "function" are all only related to the button object. Is it right? If it is right, How to access the 
array within "function"?

Comment: Make sure that the length of bu is grather than 0, put an alert before the for statment, like this: alert(bu.length);

Comment: @user3378165 Yes. It returns 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of callbacks not working in case of closure variables due to closure variable being incremented. Your variable `i` is increased to 3 even before first time the button is clicked and `contents[i]` doesn't return anything. Change your function to have an *IIFE* as below to provide lexical scoping of variable i:

```
for(var i=0; i<bu.length; i++){ 
   alert(contents[i]);
    (function (index) {
      bu[index].onclick=function(){
        alert(contents[index]);
        console.log(index);
        document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].innerHTML = contents[index]; 
       }
    })(i);  
}
```

This will lexically scope the index variable for each button click.

There was also a typo in your code that you were using `content[i]` instead of `contents[i]`

I have created a working JSBIn for same here: https://jsbin.com/fasicu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

**UPDATE**

*Document.getElementsByClassName()*

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.

So in order to access even a single element you need to access it from the array-like object using index `0`

Refer MDN for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: For alert it properly work. But it doesn't change the content of div("data") element.

Comment: There was 1 more issue that `document.getElementsByClassName("data")` will return a NodeList and not an element. To access the div with class `data` you need to access the lement at index `0` in NodeList. I have update the code and JSBIN link for the fix of same

Comment: Thanks man. So what is the need of 0. The program contains only one div element with class "data". So, why I need to specify as "document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].innerHTML = contents[index];" instead of "document.getElementsByClassName("data").innerHTML = contents[index];"

Comment: I have updated the requirement for this in the answer for someone else referring in future

Answer (score 2):

> Use [**`Closures`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) so that returned function will remember the environment in which it is created.

As events are being registered in a `loop`, by the time `click-handler` is invoked, value of `i` is `3` and there is no element in the `array` having index as `3`, `undefined` is returned.

Also note, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns `collection(array-like object)` which does not have property `innerHTML`, use `0th` index to grab the element or use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

---

```js
var bu = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
var contents = ["HTML", "js", "css"];
for (var i = 0; i < bu.length; i++) {
  bu[i].onclick = (function(i) {
    return function() {
      document.querySelector(".data").innerHTML = contents[i]; //correct typo here
    }
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <button class="tabs">HTM</button>
  <button class="tabs">JS</button>
  <button class="tabs">CSS</button>
</div>
<div class="data"></div>
```

Or use [**`Array#forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var bu = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
var contents = ["HTML", "js", "css"];

[].forEach.call(bu, function(item, index) {
  item.onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".data").innerHTML = contents[index];
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <button class="tabs">HTM</button>
  <button class="tabs">JS</button>
  <button class="tabs">CSS</button>
</div>
<div class="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time click event occur  the value will be the length of the array, since for loop increment `i`. So you need to use functional level variable which holds the value of `i` in iteration.

---

Also there is one more issue in your code : [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like live HTMLCollection, you need to get one element to update [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

---

You can use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in new  browser which provides block level scope to the variable.

```html
<body>
  <div class="con">
    <button class="tabs">HTM</button>
    <button class="tabs">JS</button>
    <button class="tabs">CSS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="data"></div>
  <script>
    var bu = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
    var contents = ["HTML", "js", "css"];
    for (let i = 0; i < bu.length; i++) {
      alert(contents[i]);      
      bu[i].onclick = function() {
        alert(contents[i]);
        document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].innerHTML = contents[i];
      }
    }
  </script>

  <body>
```

---

or use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and pass `i` as argument

```html
<body>
  <div class="con">
    <button class="tabs">HTM</button>
    <button class="tabs">JS</button>
    <button class="tabs">CSS</button>
  </div>
  <div class="data"></div>
  <script>
    var bu = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
    var contents = ["HTML", "js", "css"];
    for (let i = 0; i < bu.length; i++) {
      alert(contents[i]);
      (function(i) {
        bu[i].onclick = function() {
          alert(contents[i]);
          document.getElementsByClassName("data")[0].innerHTML = contents[i];
        }
      })(i)
    }
  </script>

  <body>
```

Comment: Using closure it gets worked. But it doesn't work for div("data") element. The content doesn't change after clicking the button.